# How to create a table with checkboxes yii2

Tags: php, html, yii2

How can I create a table of the same kind as in the picture using yii2? The problem is that I cannot configure checkboxList in ActiveForm so that it integrates into the html table.
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQJtg.png)

Comment: Neither the problem nor the question are very clear. Please provide some code examples or further explanation. What exactly are you trying to do, where is the problem, what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a gridvieew with checkbox column

```
'columns' => [
 // ...
  [
    'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
    // you may configure additional properties here
  ],
]
```

You can see useful info in these docs

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-checkboxcolumn

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-widgets#grid-view
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-widgets#checkbox-column